# Perl script to extract 2 lines before and after the pattern matching

Tags: perl

my file is like

```
line 1 
line 2 
line 3
target
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

I can write a regex that matches the target. What all I need is I need to grab lines 2,3,5,6.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

If you're not determined to use `perl` you can easily extract the context you want with `grep` and **Context Line Control** options

```
grep -A 2 -B 2 target filename | grep -v target
```

Of course `target` will need to be replaced by a suitable regex.

Comment: your answer includes 'target', which was excluded in the question.  You need to pipe into a `grep -v target`

Comment: and, of course, if the surrounding lines might also contain the 'target' pattern, you are in trouble

Comment: nice and simple ...  and can be integrated into a perl script with [`Capture::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) or `qx//`

Comment: @G.Cito There's also `grep -C 2...` which combines `-A` (after) and `-B` (before).

Answer (score 4):

Robert is on the right path. You have to multiline your regex and match the 2 previous and next lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $lines = <<EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
target
line 5
line 6
line 7
EOF
;

# Match a new line, then 2 lines, then target, then 2 lines.
#                { $1       }        { $3       }
my $re = qr/^.*\n((.*?\n){2})target\n((.*?\n){2}).*$/m;

(my $res = $lines) =~ s/$re/$1$3/;
print $res;
```

Comment: as pointed-out by leonbloy, your answer fails if there are multiple target strings in the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
@lines = ('line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'target', 'line 5', 'line 6', 'line 7');
my %answer;
$regex = 'target';
for my $idx (0..$#lines) {
    if ($lines[$idx] =~ /$regex/) {
        for $ii (($idx - 2)..($idx + 2)){
            unless ($lines[$ii] =~ /^$regex$/) {$answer{$ii} = $lines[$ii];}
        }
    }
}
foreach $key (sort keys %answer) { print "$answer{$key}\n" }
```

Which yields...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ perl search.pl
line 2
line 3
line 5
line 6
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

### EDIT

Fixed for @leonbloy's comment about multiple target strings in the file

Comment: what about `target` within the first or last line of the file ?

Comment: @M42 I thought of that too but I don't think this answer will be selected so I don't see the point in adding more complexity...  it is trivial for the OP to add if they want this code

Comment: Nicely done ... I realize now 5 years after your answer and two years after mine that we both use hashes but construct them differently :-) ... I updated my answer to use to include a simpler array only approach which seems to work but likely is not as fast for large files.  Never stop relearning the simple things ;-)

Answer (score 2):

slurp the file to a list / array, find the index of the matching line, and use this index to get the desired values (using offsets)

Answer (score 2):

Although this was asked 8 months ago, I had to rethink this question, since none of the findable solution met with my aims. My goal was to make a script which examines many of huge log files, and makes extracts from them, containing only the wanted lines, putting optional number of lines before and after the line which contains the searched pattern(s) WITHOUT any redundancies. I tried to reuse some of the codes found here, but none of them was good enough for me. So finally I create a unique one, which is probably not the most beautiful, but looks useful, so I'd like to share it with you:

```
use strict;

my @findwhat      = ('x');
my $extraLines    = 3;
my @cache         = ('') x ($extraLines);
my @stack;
my $lncntr        = 0;
my $hit           = 0;
my $nextHitWatch  = 0;
my $shift         = 1;

open (IN, "<test1.log");
  while (my $line=<IN>) {
    $lncntr++;
    chomp $line;
    foreach my $what (@findwhat) {if ($line =~ m/$what/i) {$hit = 1; last}}

    if ($hit && !$nextHitWatch) {
      @stack = @cache;
      $hit = 0;
      $nextHitWatch++;
    }

    if (!$hit && $nextHitWatch && $nextHitWatch < ($extraLines * 2) + 2) {
      @stack = (@stack, $line);
      $nextHitWatch++;
    }

    if (!$hit && $nextHitWatch && $nextHitWatch == ($extraLines * 2) + 2) {
      @stack = (@stack, $line);
      for (my $i = 0; $i <= ($#stack - ($extraLines + $shift)); $i++) {
        print $stack[$i]. "\n" if $stack[$i];
      }
      $nextHitWatch = 0;
      $shift = 1;
      @stack = ();
    }

    if ($nextHitWatch >= 1 && eof) {
      foreach(@stack) {print "$_\n"}
    }

    if ($nextHitWatch >= 1 && eof) {
      if (!$hit) {
        my $upValue = 3 + $#stack - ($nextHitWatch - $extraLines + $shift);
        $upValue = ($upValue > $#stack) ? $#stack : $upValue;
        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $upValue; $i++) {
          print $stack[$i] . "\n";
        }
      } else {
        foreach (@stack) {print "$_\n"}
      }
    }

    shift(@cache);
    push(@cache, $line);
  }
close (IN);
```

Probably, you will have to change only the values of the list @findwhat and the scalar $extraLines. I hope my code will be useable. (Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

multiline the regex, eg: `/\n{3}(foo)\n{3}/m;`

**edit**
`/\n*(foo)\n*/m` works in the general case

Comment: I don't understand why I'm voted down here. The question was specific, a regex that matches the input. My regex does match the input. If he wanted to generalize for various other inputs, he should have asked for it. As it is, we don't know if he wants to generalize on variable # of targets within a block of lines, or variable # of lines between targets, or both.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but it is deserved. Did you try it ? Your regex is trying to match `3 linefeeds` then `foo` then `3 linefeeds` that's not at all what the OP wants.

Comment: @M42 foo isnt literal .. its *hugely* common especially with perl but in general, to use "foo", "foobar", etc, as placards for whatever the data is that is to be matched.  I could have said "target", as the author did .. but I guess I falsely assumed some primitive understanding necessary to make use of regexes in general. my bad :P

Comment: `foo` isn't the problem, the 3 linefeeds are.

Comment: :D come on man. `line 1`, `line 2` were to "\n" what `target` was to *foobar* - ps, still not corrective bump on the rating :S

Answer (score 0):

One liner version (where `-l` = `chomp` and `-n` = `while(<>){}`. See `perldoc`[`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more options):

```
perl -lnE '$h{$.}=$_; END { 
  for ( grep { $h{$_} eq "target" } sort{ $a <=> $b } keys %h ) { 
  say for @h{$_-2..$_-1 , $_+1..$_+2} } }' data.txt
```

Script with explanation:

```
#!perl
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  $hash{$.} = $_  ; # hash entry with line number as key; line contents as value
}

# find the target in the hash and sort keys or line numbers into an array
@matches = sort {$a <=> $b} grep { $hash{$_} eq 'target' } keys %hash;

for (@matches) { 
  say "before\n" ;
  say for @hash{$_-2..$_-1} ; # print the context lines as a hash slice
  say ">>>>\" $hash{$.} \"<<<< " ;
  say "after\n" ;
  say for @hash{$_+1..$_+2} ;
  say "";
}

__DATA__
line 1
line 2
line 3
target
line 5
line 6
line 7
target
line of context1
line of context2
target
```

**Output**:

```
before
line 2
line 3
>>>>" target "<<<< 
after
line 5
line 6

before
line 6
line 7
>>>>" target "<<<< 
after
line of context1
line of context2

before
line of context1
line of context2
>>>>" target "<<<< 
after
```

A simpler version using only arrays and with output that excludes the target as the OP question requested:

```
#!perl -l     
chomp( my @lines = <DATA> ) ; 
my $n = 2 ; # context range before/after

my @indexes = grep { $lines[$_] =~ m/target/ } 0..$#lines ; 
foreach my $i (@indexes) { 
  print for @lines[$i-$n..$i-1], @lines[$i+1..$i+$n],"";
}

__DATA__
line 1
line 2
line 3
target
line 5
line 6
line 7
target
line of context1
line of context2
target
```

This avoids constructing the hash but may be slower on very large files/arrays.

On CPAN [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) has `indexes()` and there is always `splice()`, but I'm not sure these would make things simpler.